# adding to the value in a hash table

Tags: ruby, hash

I am trying to increment the value in a hash by one.  My logic seems right, but for some reason my value in the hash is not incrementing by one.

```
  puts item_sold
  temp = sales_hash.values[item_sold] + 1
  sales_hash.values[item_sold] = temp
  puts sales_hash.values[item_sold]
```

`sales_hash` is a hash where the key is a number between 1000-2000 and the value for each key starts at 0.  `item_sold` is a random number between 1 and 15.  There are 15 items in the hash. When `temp` prints out it is a value of one.  However when I print out the value of `sales_hash.values[item_sold]` it prints 0.  What is `sales_hash.values[item_sold]` not incrementing?

Comment: if `item_sold` is a hash, you shouldn't be able to put it as an array index.

Answer (score 2):

[`Hash#values`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Hash.html#method-i-values) returns an array of of all the hashes values.  You want to add to one value, which you'd do like this:

```
item_sold
=> {0=>0, 1=>0, 2=>0}
item_sold[0] += 1
=> 1
item_sold
=> {0=>1, 1=>0, 2=>0}
```

You access the value of a hash by by using the `hash[key]` syntax.